# typescript - while not allowing implicit any types

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, knockout-validation

We have chosen not to allow any implicit any types in our project however we are using 3rd party ko.validation libary

We are getting error on the following

```
ko.validation.rules['minArrayLength'] = {
    validator: function (obj: any, params: any) {
        return obj.length >= params.minLength;
    },
    message: "Array does not meet minimum length requirements"
};
```

**Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.**

The error is on ko.validation.rules['minArrayLength']

How can we not allow any but still use ko.validation.rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to `KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions` interface via declaration merging:

```
interface KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions {
    minArrayLength: KnockoutValidationRuleDefinition;
}
```

That will define the rule on `ko.validation.rules`, thereby removing the implicit any error.

If you are using external modules, make sure to put this interface in your own definition file (`.d.ts`).

Comment: that looks like the right thing to do if it's not already defined, but it doesn't seem to explain the error, since `['minArrayLength']` isn't restricted by the type def.

Comment: @mk. by doing this, `ko.validation.rules['minArrayLength']` will have a type of `KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions` instead of `any` and it will fix the error.

Comment: `rules["anything"]` [isn't typed](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20x%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Ax.foo%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0Ax%5B%22foo%22%5D%20%3D%201%3B), except via index signature typing, such as `interface Rules {  [key: string]: KValRuleDef; }`.

Comment: @mk. that example doesn't demonstrate it properly. See [here](http://goo.gl/ZuTGss). With `noImplicitAny` the `myNonExistantProperty` line would be an error.

Comment: @mk. no problem. I think it was in one of the past recent versions they changed it to be able to do that. I can't remember when. Glad to help though :)

Comment: Yes this solved the 'index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type' error message i was getting